# Trouble with creating a popover withs storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, storyboard, popover

I cannot create a popover with storyboard.
The settings are as follows:
The github repo: https://github.com/li354886/iOSProjects/tree/v1.1/testPopOver
I viewed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5XFMpXLwZQ
The popover view controller just behaves as modal.

Comment: I did view this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5XFMpXLwZQ

Comment: Hi could you tell us where you suspect the error might be. Do you have a prepareForSegue or a change of view controller called, simply giving a link to github instead of sharing code doesn't really entice people to help. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I have figured it out. All the issues were about UI design without code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your app is Universal. You won't see any popovers, by default, on an iPhone-only app. (You can see them in iOS 8, with some extra work, but by default you won't.)

Comment: Thank you! I have figured it out!